# App crashes when trying to establish VPN connection?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-vpn-service

According to the doc [`VpnService.prepare(context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#prepare(android.content.Context)) is used to establish a VPN connection in android, and it's doing the trick in almost all device models except specific ones **( Oppo X9076 Android 5.0 )**. As per the logs from within the crashlytics call to [`VpnService.prepare(context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#prepare(android.content.Context)) cause the SDK break internally. Not sure whether it's a device specific issue or what!. below is the log from crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.server.connectivity.Vpn.prepare(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.prepareVpn(IConnectivityManager.java:1663)
at android.net.VpnService.prepare(VpnService.java:159)
```

*I've given everything, not to exempt an extensive search on the web as well, yet to make a way out. Pl. help me out, I'm stuck here all the way.*

**FYR**

- [Issue #1084](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardForAndroid/issues/1084)